# Missing Farm Configuration Wizard

Tags: configuration-wizard

I am installing SharePoint 2010 single farm on my 64bit Win7 Ultimate development machine. After a lot of pain and apparent success of the installation, I am not finding the "Farm Configuration Wizard" on the "Configuration Wizards" page of Central Administration.

Looking for reasons why and things to check to make it show up.

Comment: Did you select NTLM or Kerberos authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I saw this again today.  I logged in under with farm admin account and the wizard showed up. SO this appears to be a security related issue.

Answer (score 4):

Farm configuration wizard does not support a stand alone farm installation.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you try to go to the url directly?
http://myserver:portnumber/_admin/adminconfigintro.aspx?scenarioid=adminconfig&welcomestringid=farmconfigurationwizard_welcome

Answer (score 1):

I saw this issue today and figured out that for me it was related to how I launched Internet Explorer.

I was connected via remote desktop and if I started Internet Explorer via the start menu, navigated to the central administration site and authenticated as a user who's a member of the farm administrator group I would be presented with an empty 'Configuration Wizards' section. Also note that the 'New' button in the ribbon under 'Manage Web Applications' was disabled.

If I closed Internet Explorer and navigated to 'Start > All Programs > SharePoint 2010 Products' and ran the shortcut there to 'SharePoint 2010 Central Administration' after answering yes to a UAC prompt and authenticating as the same user used previously the 'Farm Configuration' wizard was available. Note also that the 'New' button under 'Manage Web Applications' was also available.

Comment: this was my issue...ty

Answer (score 1):

You can run it on a Stand Alone Installation.  Just make sure to add the Central Admin URL in Local Intranet Zone (IE Security Tab).  Close your current browser, click central admin out of the program menu which should automatically log you in.

I have seen where the machine needs a re-boot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you start Internet Explorer using elevated privilegies.

Comment: Still is not visible.  Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue - SP2010 was installed, didn't get any error messages, but the "Configuration Wizards" section in CA displays a blank page.

IE is running as an Administrator
Going to the page described above results in an access denied page (Is this a authentication issue? I'm definitely configured as the farm admin.)

Comment: Did you solve this? I can't seem to make it...

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled and that problem has not shown up again.  Yet!